# Is it possible to run a java program inside a Junit test?

Tags: java, testing, junit

Context:

My company has a tool written in Java, that is run on the command line interface. To run this tool on the command line:

```
gradle clean
gradle build
cd multiple times
unpack rar files 
./run_tool.sh parameter1 parameter2 parameter3
```

My company also has an automation test codebase that consists of JUnit tests. I have to write an automated test that runs the tool.

I know it is possible to run a script inside a Java program. However, the examples I saw did not show how to run a script with parameters. Furthermore, the examples I saw were simple scripts, not full Java programs.

I do not know if what I am trying to do is even possible. Can anyone please suggest potential approaches?

Comment: That example isn't running a Java program from the command line, it is running a bash script.

Answer (score 0):

If the tool is written in Java, it may make more sense to use its classes directly in JUnit tests. You'd have to publish the tool as JAR files in your corporate Maven repository (Nexus, Artifactory, etc), and hook it up in your tests as Maven/Gradle dependency.

Executing a shell command from Java is certainly possible, but it's much more complicated.